# Is there an elegant one liner to append scopes stored in an array using .send()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scopes

Here is what I have

currently, I'm doing this:

```
current_account.send(object).search(params[:search]).user_id_equals_any(users).visibility_is_any(visibilities)
```

but thats not very flexible? What if I want to conditionally not have one of those scopes?

I figure an array of scopes with conditionally added elements would be a good solution

An array of parameters that I would invoke using .send()

```
scopes = []    
scopes = << [:user_id_equals_any, users] if filter_users
    scopes = << [:visibility_is_any, visibilities] if filter_visibility
```

So, I could have some unknown number scopes.

To execute the scopes, I need to invoke `.send(:scope_name, scope_param)`

But How do I do that for any number of scopes in my `scopes` array?

As a loop, I think It would be something like

```
result = current_account.send(object).search(params[:search])
scopes.each do |scope|
    result.send(scope[0], scope[1])
end
return result
```

the loop can be simplified to

```
scopes.each {|s| result.send(s[0], s[1]) }
```

but is there a way to append the different send calls in one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
scopes = []
# Note that in your example, the assignment is invalid syntax
scopes << [:user_id_equals_any, users] if filter_users
scopes << [:visibility_is_any, visibilities] if filter_visibility

# initial result
result = current_account.send(object).search(params[:search])

# applying the scopes
result = scopes.inject(result) do |result, (method, param)|
  result.send(method, param)
end
return result
```

In each loop, the last return value of the previous block execution gets passed the first parameter of the block, in this case `result`. The first loop gets the initial result (i.e. the parameter in square brackets to the `inject` call. The return value of the last loop gets returned.

For more details, have a look at [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).

Comment: why is the object in teh inject do block `response`?

Comment: @TheLindyHop: It was a typo that just got fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to build your own abstractions so your code reflects how you think about a problem:

```
class Object
  def send_if(condition, *args, &block)
    condition ? send(*args, &block) : self
  end
end

current_account.send(object).search(params[:search]).
  send_if(filter_user, :user_id_equals_any, users).
  send_if(filter_visibility, :visibility_is_any, visibilities)
```

Comment: why is the third param a block?I thought send was just `.send(name, params)`

Comment: @TheLindyHop: you may want to send a block to the wrapped method, it's just to make it more generic even though it's not being used in the example.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how that would be used? the original .send doesn't take a block http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send

Comment: example with _squeel_ (AR wrapper): `User.send_if(condition, :where) { id > 1 }.all`. I don't know why the documentation shows no block for `send` (maybe it's implicit in `args...`) but rest assured you can pass a block to `send` and it will be passed to the object, otherwise it'd be pretty useless.

Comment: I'm not sure if this solution is really better than mine. You still have long call chains (which even span three lines) and you "pollute" every object with your method. While it is indeed rather generic, it still doesn't allow to prepare the `scopes` array somewhere and then just apply it in a single location. You still "hardcode" the calls and parameters.

Comment: @Holger: I was just providing an alternative, I am also surprised it got chosen. In fact I use your scopes+inject a lot. Regarding the "pollution" of `Object`... have you taken a look at the bunch of method already there? :-) IMHO it's not against Ruby's philosophy to add methods to base classes as long as they are generic. That's a great thing of Ruby, it allows to build your own abstractions, you're not constraint by the core devs choices.

Comment: @tokland: A basic Ruby 1.8.7 has 45 instance methods on `Object`, the majority from `Kernel`, only when using Rails, that number grows significantly. Also, while I do like to extend base classes with nifty functionality when it's justified, I *really* look forward for the [refinements](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4085) (hopefully) available with Ruby 2.0 which will allow scoped inclusion of modules, preventing the pollution of the global namespace for everyone.

Comment: @HolgerJust: Thanks for the link to refinements, I wasn't aware of that proposal. Object method count for 1.9.3 went up to 63 :-(